# HTML CSS - sticky footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried many different 'sticky footer' techniques, but for some reason I cannot get this to work on my site: http://codeandco.net/services/

Any ideas?

Note: this is different to a fixed footer. I'm trying to get the footer to 'stick' to the bottom of the window, but underneath any of the page content - like this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: You may need to zoom out on your browser to see what I'm referring to

Answer (score 1):

add these 4 lines to `#footer` in your CSS

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: Close - but it doesn't display under the page content.
i.e. it covers the page content when you decrease the browser height

Comment: main { margin-bottom: 72px; }

Comment: Still doesn't change anything sorry

Answer (score 1):

Code below worked. 
Note: the 'footer-push' was the key to getting this to work:

```
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto -75px !important; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

footer, .footer-push {
    height: 75px !important; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Some references from: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the way: use [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/).**

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

And don't forget this:

```
body {
margin-bottom: 60px;
}

html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need footer to be **fixed**, change footer style to this:

```
#footer {
background: #CCC;
color: #787878;
font-size: 13px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
}
```

But don't forget to add padding for body:

```
body {
padding-bottom: 60px !important;
}
```

...or

```
main {
margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This has some strange effects on the footer. I've updated my CSS to include your changes - still not 100%. Footer creeps up the page when you scroll down (when you decrease browser window height, for e.g.)

Comment: Just use {position: fixed} for the footer to make it be always in the bottom side of the content. Please take a look at a code above, it's updated.

Comment: Still no go. I tried your revised code, but the footer display's over the page content when a scroll bar is present. See here: http://imgur.com/ObjVMs4

Comment: Of course it does :). You need also to add: main { margin-bottom: 75px; } So the content will have a margin.

Comment: I wish it was so, but still having issues - sorry to be a pain! I've updated my CSS again (have another look with element inspector) - to exactly what you say

Comment: Welcome, hope the next example will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer
{   
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    float:left;
}
```